# Duplicating event posts in wordpress

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm facing a problem for days now.

In order to make a events calendar wp Website (witout plugin), I have a CPT "Event" with a custom field "event_dates".
The custom field is build this way : 2023-03-17 04:23,2023-03-19 04:23, ...

I can make a classical WP_query in order to display post belong to the (first) "event_date" taxonomy but i can't figure out to how dulicate this in results in order to display those events (posts) on multiple days.

I've tried some in vain, but I think it's perhaps possible to inject posts from pre_get_posts() function. I tried with "post__in", but it dosen't seem to accept duplicate post IDS.

I also tried to catch all posts events and working with a foreach on "event_dates" : it works, but I loose all wordpress pagination system.

I don't really need the code for it more than a reflexion to achieve it.

A help or a start of idea would be really appreciated, I'm stuck ! :)

Take care,
Nico

UPDATE /
For each dates of "event_dates" post meta, I request a new query with the current ID and I merge the result posts array with the inital query posts array.
This works if I forgot the pagination and so put everything is on the same page.
This code does not appear in pre_get_post but before looping to display.

```
function do_loop($my_query) {



    // $event_list_count = $my_query->found_posts;

    $event_list_output = "";

    $event_month = "";

    $event_day = "";

    $event_month_open = 0;

    $event_day_open = 0;

    $event_day_open_count = 0;

    $start_date_old = new DateTime('2001-02-03 00:00');

    $today = date( 'Ymd H:i' );

    $the_posts= array();



    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

            global $post;

            $ghost_dates = get_field( 'event_dates' );

            // FORMAT 2023-04-08 15:34 ...

            $ghost_post_date_current = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', substr( $ghost_dates, 0, 10 ) );
            // $ghost_post_date_current = substr( $ghost_dates, 0, 10 );

            $post->date_temp = $ghost_post_date_current->format("Ymd");

            if ( !has_term( 'reunion', 'events_cats', get_the_ID() ) ) :

                $ghost_dates_array = explode(",", $ghost_dates );

                foreach( $ghost_dates_array as $key => $ghost_post_date ) :

                    if( $key != 0 ) :

                        $ghost_post_date_array = explode("||", $ghost_post_date );

                        $ghost_post_date_current = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i', $ghost_post_date_array[0] );

                        // echo $ghost_post_date_current->format("Ymd");

                        if ( $ghost_post_date_current->format("Ymd H:i") >= $today ) :

                            $my_query_temp = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'post__in' => array( get_the_ID() ) ) );

                            if( $my_query_temp->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query_temp->have_posts() ) : $my_query_temp->the_post();

                                global $post;

                                $post->date_temp = $ghost_post_date_current->format("Ymd");

                            endwhile; endif;

                            $the_posts = array_merge( $the_posts, $my_query_temp->posts );

                        endif;

                    endif;

                endforeach;

            endif;

        endwhile;

        $all_together = array_merge( $my_query->posts, $the_posts );

        $sort = array();

        foreach ($all_together as $key => $row) {

            $sort[$key] = $row->date_temp;

        }

        array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $all_together);

        $my_query->posts = $all_together;

        $my_query->found_posts = count( $all_together );

        $my_query->post_count = 4;

        $my_query->max_num_pages = ceil( $my_query->found_posts / $my_query->post_count );

    endif;
```

I know a workig practice is to create clones of the event post with differents dates. And I've done it before, because I have an online front end form for connected users to create to create/manage events.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the (first) "event_date" taxonomy*" and "*tried to catch all posts events*"? What taxonomy and events are they? And, "*working with a foreach on "event_dates" : it works*" - what's your code?

Comment: you mentioned that you have a custom field which implies post meta, but then you say taxonomy which is not post meta, can you edit your question to clear up the confusion? Use the edit link under the tag list to do this. Taxonomies/terms are tags/categories/etc and have their own tables functions and APIs, they're completely separate to post meta which is used by the custom fields metabox, or plugins such as ACF. The difference is super important and critical to understanding your question. Also include code!

Comment: sorry "event_dates" is a Custom post Meta (ACF)

Comment: I perhaps try to see with ajax after the page load, in order to add events blocs in the main list displayed by the wp loop.

Comment: `new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'post__in' => array( get_the_ID() ) ) )` - is that really necessary? Why not just do `$the_posts[] = get_post();` ? But honestly, I still don't fully understand what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I need a list by date (post meta) of posts with duplicated posts for the multiple dates events. Like in a calendar.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for more than a bunch of code, an approach to think about.

Comment: I probably will solve my issue by using taxonomy instead of meta posts.
I loose the WP pagination ;(, but I've seen a kind of solution to paginate a foreach.